# Convert text string into JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a file with data written by a lua script that I am trying to convert into JSON. The data is formatted as follows:

```
{"ID" : 51, "name" : "John", "relationship" : "Friend", "Lat" : 56.166609, "Long" : 27.157364}
{"ID" : 52, "name" : "Sally", "relationship" : "Friend", "Lat" : 55.895501, "Long" : 26.753631}
```

I need to convert it to:

```
[
    {
"time" : 0.00, 
"ID" : 51, 
"name" : "John",
"relationship" : "Friend",
"Lat" : 56.166609, 
"Long" : 27.157364
},
{
    "time" : 0.00, 
    "ID" : 52, 
    "name" : "Sally",
    "relationship" : "Friend",
    "Lat" : 55.895501, 
    "Long" : 26.753631
    }
]
```

Currently I am trying the code below, which works with a single line of data but not with multiple lines of data. I haven't been able to figure out what additional steps are needed for multilpe lines (the actual data file will be hundreds of lines) :

```
        const response2 = await fetch('Export.log');
        var data2 = await response2.text();
        var formatted = JSON.parse(data2);
        console.log(formatted);
```

Comment: you need format json output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to take `data2` and do the following.

```
var formatted = JSON.parse('[' + data2.trim().replace(/\n/g, ',') + ']')
```

So take your data, replace all of the new lines with commas, and then wrap it in an array.

The trim is to take off a trailing new line if there are any.